# string with format as argument for method (objective-c)

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsstring

The `[NSString stringWithFormat:];` can take multiple arguments even though it's declared as NSString not NSArray and there's only one colon.

How can I have this for my own method, which is like a replacement for NSLog that writes to a text field so it's used often and I don't want to keep adding more square brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an ellipsis after your argument name:

```
 (NSNumber *) addValues:(int) count, ...;
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocDefiningClasses.html

You then need to use `va_list` and `va_start` to iterate through the arguments provided:

```
- (NSNumber *) addValues:(int) count, ...
{
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, count);

  NSNumber *value;

  double retval;

  for( int i = 0; i < count; i++ )
  {
    value = va_arg(args, NSNumber *);

    retval += [value doubleValue];

  }

  va_end(args);
  return [NSNumber numberWithDouble:retval];
}
```

Example from: http://numbergrinder.com/node/35

Note that this is a built-in C functionality, not part of Objective-C specifically; there is a good explanation of the va_arg usage here:

http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter9/stdarg.html

Comment: how would I do do this with stringWithFormat? say I want a method called `titleWithFormat:`

Comment: Your method signature would be  -(NSString *) titleWithFormat:(NSString *)format, ...;

Comment: And my second link provides examples that use a while loop instead of a for loop, which you can use to loop through each of the args provided. If what you want is the same as stringWithFormat though; you should just be able to call that method and pass the arguments through.